# Steady State parameter estimation for CSTR using GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I would like to fit the reaction constants (k0 and EoverR) using steady-state concentration data of a CSTR with respect to the reactor temperature.
I used just a simple linear equation to generate the operation data to fit. (Ca_data = -1.5*T_reactor/100 + 4.2)

Because this is steady-state data, there is no time step (m.time) needed. Please give advice on how to convert below simulation code into an estimation code for 'Ca vs. T_reactor'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Feed Temperature (K)
Tf = 350
# Feed Concentration (mol/m^3)
Caf = 1

# Steady State Initial Conditions for the States
Ca_ss = 1
T_ss = 304

#%% GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = np.linspace(0, 25, 251)

# Volumetric Flowrate (m^3/sec)
q = 100
# Volume of CSTR (m^3)
V = 100
# Density of A-B Mixture (kg/m^3)
rho = 1000
# Heat capacity of A-B Mixture (J/kg-K)
Cp = 0.239
# Heat of reaction for A->B (J/mol)
mdelH = 5e4
# E - Activation energy in the Arrhenius Equation (J/mol)
# R - Universal Gas Constant = 8.31451 J/mol-K
EoverR = 8700
# Pre-exponential factor (1/sec)
k0 = 3.2e15
# U - Overall Heat Transfer Coefficient (W/m^2-K)
# A - Area - this value is specific for the U calculation (m^2)
UA = 5e4

# initial conditions = 280
T0 = 304
Ca0 = 1.0

T = m.MV(value=T_ss)
rA = m.Var(value=0)
Ca = m.CV(value=Ca_ss)

m.Equation(rA == k0*m.exp(-EoverR/T)*Ca)
m.Equation(Ca.dt() == q/V*(Caf - Ca) - rA)

m.options.IMODE = 1
m.options.SOLVER = 3

T_reactor = np.linspace(220, 260, 11)
Ca_results = np.zeros(np.size(T_reactor))
for i in range(np.size(T_reactor)):
    T.Value = T_reactor[i]
    m.solve(disp=True)
    Ca_results[i] = Ca[-1]

Ca_data = -1.5*T_reactor/100 + 4.2 # for generating the operation data

# Plot the results
plt.plot(T_reactor,Ca_data,'bo',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(T_reactor,Ca_results,'r-',linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel('Ca (mol/L)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.legend(['Reactor Concentration'],loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [steady state estimation mode](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Modes) (`IMODE=2`) in Gekko for linear or nonlinear regression. Two examples are [nonlinear regression](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ParameterFit) and [energy price regression](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/NonlinearRegression). For the posted problem, here are a few recommendations:

- Solve the regression problem with one solve, instead of in a loop. That way, the parameters that you select will fit over the entire range, not just at one point.
- Identify the parameters that should be adjusted to minimize the error between the data and model predictions. These should be an `m.FV()` type for parameters that are one value and `m.MV()` for parameters that have a different value for each time point.
- Set `Ca.FSTATUS=1` to tell the solver that it should try to match the predictions of `Ca` to the data loaded in `Ca.value`.
- Set `kf.STATUS=1` to tell the solver that it is a parameter that should be adjusted to minimize the `Ca` error.
- Optional: make `kf` the adjustable parameter instead of `k0` directly to improve problem scaling. Large values (such as >1e10 or <-1e10) can create problems for the solver (without automatic scaling) because the gradients are small. I created the new parameter `kf` as an Intermediate to also remove an additional equation.

[image: Regression Fit]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
Tf = 350
Caf = 1
q = 100
V = 100
rho = 1000
Cp = 0.239
mdelH = 5e4
EoverR = 8700
k0 = 3.2e15
UA = 5e4
T = m.MV()
Ca = m.CV()

# new parameter to estimate
kf = m.FV(1,lb=0.5,ub=2.0)
kf.STATUS = 1

rA = m.Intermediate(kf*k0*m.exp(-EoverR/T)*Ca)
m.Equation(Ca.dt() == q/V*(Caf - Ca) - rA)

m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 3

# generate data
T_reactor = np.linspace(220, 260, 11)
Ca_data = -1.5*T_reactor/100 + 4.2

# insert data
T.value = T_reactor
Ca.value = Ca_data
Ca.FSTATUS = 1 # fit Ca

m.solve()

print('kf = ' + str(kf.value[0]))
print('k = ' + str(kf.value[0]*k0))

# Plot the results
plt.plot(T_reactor,Ca_data,'bo',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(T_reactor,Ca.value,'r-',linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel('Ca (mol/L)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.legend(['Reactor Concentration','Regression Fit'],loc='best')
plt.show()
```

You can select any number of parameters to estimate to improve the fit. It doesn't need to be limited to just `kf`. Your post mentions that `EoverR` is another potential parameter to estimate but this may not improve the fit substantially because `k0` and `EoverR` are co-linear. Both parameters can be increased or decreased and give nearly the same solution. As a word of caution, there needs to be significant temperature variation to estimate both.